# How to do a raw sql query with DbContext (one connection per request)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently following this instructions on how to do a query with raw sql on ef.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql

Is it possible to do a raw sql read query(ies) on a database context in such a way so we are sure, that we use only one database connection during request processing.

Similar to this, but with DBContext instead od IDBConnection.

```
public class SqlConnectionFactory : ISqlConnectionFactory, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        private IDbConnection _connection;

        public SqlConnectionFactory(string connectionString)
        {
            this._connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        public IDbConnection GetOpenConnection()
        {
            if (this._connection == null || this._connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                this._connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
                this._connection.Open();
            }

            return this._connection;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (this._connection != null && this._connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                this._connection.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you want to manually open a transaction before the first query and commit+dispose after the last query. Otherwise I probably don't understand the actual problem you are trying to solve here (however, since you talk about reads, a transaction commit wouldn't really make sense). In fact, it doesn't make sense to ensure a single opened connection when we talk about reads only - does it?

Comment: Why do you think it doesnt make sense to prevent x db connections to open for x reads?

Comment: I think it doesn't make sense to enforce this behavior in your code. Many providers will opt for a default connection pooling on a low level, so chances are good that you actually work with a single opened connection when you just run your queries and ignore the details. So, if you have an actual issue with slow connection speed, it might be worth investigating. But if you just *assume* you should manually handle your connection, then you probably waste your and everyones time without need.